# Swift String opposite of trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet)

Tags: swift, string

In Swift is there an opposite/complement to `String.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet)`, something like `keepingCharacters(in: CharacterSet)`.
Instead of removing characters from `CharacterSet` like `trimmingCharacters` does, `keepingCharacters` should keep characters from `CharacterSet` and remove all characters not present in the `CharacterSet`.

eg:

```
let str1 = "1:22 PM"
let keeping = str1.keepingCharacters(in: .alphanumerics)
// should return "122PM"
```

Comment: How does it determine the suffix `PM` with `.alphanumerics` only? I'm assuming that you want to keep the number and trim any character from start or end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly spoken this is not a complement because the function `trimmingCharacters` removes only characters from the beginning and end of the string.

A possible way is to `filter` unwanted characters

```
let str1 = "1:22 PM"
let keeping = String(str1.filter{$0.isLetter || $0.isNumber})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `String` extension I used on another project I worked on. I think it can help with what you are trying to achieve:

```
extension String {
    func keepingCharacters(in characterSets: [CharacterSet]) -> String {
        let combinedCharacterSet = characterSets.reduce(CharacterSet()) { $0.union($1) }
        return String(self.filter { combinedCharacterSet.contains(UnicodeScalar(String($0))!) })
    }
}
```

This way I could specify what I wanted to keep, but if you only want to keep `.alphanumerics` you can adapt it easily.

```
"1:22 PM".keepingCharacters(in: [.alphanumerics, .punctuationCharacters, .whitespaces])
//"1:22 PM"

"1:22 PM".keepingCharacters(in: [.alphanumerics, .whitespaces])
//"122 PM"

"1:22 PM".keepingCharacters(in: [.alphanumerics])
//"122PM"
```